# Undefined reference to a function defined in the same file

Tags: c++, linker, undefined-reference, gsoap

I am compiling a code generated with gsoap, and I should compile some files provided by gsoap in `/usr/share/gsoap/plugin/` too.

The problem is that in linking step, I get undefined reference error:

```
wsseapi.o: In function `soap_wsse_verify_Timestamp':
wsseapi.cpp:(.text+0xf64): undefined reference to `soap_wsa_sender_fault_subcode'
```

... and a lot more to the same symbol.

The symbol however is defined in the same file as `soap_wsse_verify_Timestamp` that uses it and when I check the object file with readelf, the symbol is defined in it:

```
$ readelf -Ws wsseapi.o |grep soap_wsa_sender_fault_subcode
   164: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND soap_wsa_sender_fault_subcode
```

Here is the function definitions in the original file:

```
/**
@fn int soap_wsse_verify_Timestamp(struct soap *soap)
@brief Verifies the Timestamp/Expires element against the current time.
@param soap context
@return SOAP_OK or SOAP_FAULT with wsse:FailedAuthentication fault

Sets wsse:FailedAuthentication fault if wsu:Timestamp is expired. The
SOAP_WSSE_CLKSKEW value is used as a margin to mitigate clock skew. Keeps
silent when no timestamp is supplied or no expiration date is included in the
wsu:Timestamp element.
*/
int
soap_wsse_verify_Timestamp(struct soap *soap)
{ _wsu__Timestamp *timestamp = soap_wsse_Timestamp(soap);
  DBGFUN("soap_wsse_verify_Timestamp");
  /* if we have a timestamp with an expiration date, check it */
  if (timestamp && timestamp->Expires)
  { time_t now = time(NULL), expired;
    soap_s2dateTime(soap, timestamp->Expires, &expired);
    if (expired + SOAP_WSSE_CLKSKEW <= now)
    { const char *code = soap_wsu__tTimestampFault2s(soap, wsu__MessageExpired);
      return soap_wsse_sender_fault_subcode(soap, code, "Message has expired", timestamp->Expires);
    }
  }
  return SOAP_OK;
}
```

and

```
/**
@fn int soap_wsse_sender_fault_subcode(struct soap *soap, const char *faultsubcode, const char *faultstring, const char *faultdetail)
@brief Sets sender SOAP Fault (sub)code for server fault response.
@param soap context
@param[in] faultsubcode sub code string
@param[in] faultstring fault string
@param[in] faultdetail detail string
@return SOAP_FAULT
*/
int
soap_wsse_sender_fault_subcode(struct soap *soap, const char *faultsubcode, const char *faultstring, const char *faultdetail)
{
#if defined(SOAP_WSA_2003) || defined(SOAP_WSA_2004) || defined(SOAP_WSA_200408) || defined(SOAP_WSA_2005)
  return soap_wsa_sender_fault_subcode(soap, faultsubcode, faultstring, faultdetail);
#else
  return soap_sender_fault_subcode(soap, faultsubcode, faultstring, faultdetail);
#endif
}
```

finally,

```
/**
@fn int soap_wsa_sender_fault_subcode(struct soap *soap, const char *faultsubcode, const char *faultstring, const char *faultdetail)
@brief Sets sender SOAP Fault (sub)code for server fault response.
@param soap context
@param[in] faultsubcode sub code string
@param[in] faultstring fault string
@param[in] faultdetail detail string
@return SOAP_FAULT
*/
int
soap_wsa_sender_fault_subcode(struct soap *soap, const char *faultsubcode, const char *faultstring, const char *faultdetail)
{ return soap_wsa_fault_subcode(soap, 1, faultsubcode, faultstring, faultdetail);
}
```

My question is how can an undefined reference error occur when the symbol is defined in the same file and can be find in the same object file.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Here is the definition part in a header file included in the top of the cpp file:

```
int soap_wsa_request(struct soap *soap, const char *id, const char *to, const char *action);
int soap_wsa_add_From(struct soap *soap, const char *endpoint);
int soap_wsa_add_NoReply(struct soap *soap);
int soap_wsa_add_ReplyTo(struct soap *soap, const char *endpoint);
int soap_wsa_add_FaultTo(struct soap *soap, const char *endpoint);
int soap_wsa_add_RelatesTo(struct soap *soap, const char *endpoint);
const char *soap_wsa_From(struct soap *soap);
const char *soap_wsa_ReplyTo(struct soap *soap);
const char *soap_wsa_FaultTo(struct soap *soap);
const char *soap_wsa_RelatesTo(struct soap *soap);

int soap_wsa_check(struct soap *soap);
int soap_wsa_reply(struct soap *soap, const char *id, const char *action);
int soap_wsa_fault_subcode(struct soap *soap, int flag, const char *faultsubcode, const char *faultstring, const char *faultdetail);
int soap_wsa_fault_subcode_action(struct soap *soap, int flag, const char *faultsubcode, const char *faultstring, const char *faultdetail, const char *action);
int soap_wsa_sender_fault_subcode(struct soap *soap, const char *faultsubcode, const char *faultstring, const char *faultdetail);
int soap_wsa_sender_fault_subcode_action(struct soap *soap, const char *faultsubcode, const char *faultstring, const char *faultdetail, const char *action);
int soap_wsa_receiver_fault_subcode(struct soap *soap, const char *faultsubcode, const char *faultstring, const char *faultdetail);
int soap_wsa_receiver_fault_subcode_action(struct soap *soap, const char *faultsubcode, const char *faultstring, const char *faultdetail, const char *action);
int soap_wsa_sender_fault(struct soap *soap, const char *faultstring, const char *faultdetail);
int soap_wsa_receiver_fault(struct soap *soap, const char *faultstring, const char *faultdetail);
```

**UPDATE:**
The problem seems to be due the linking problem between C++ and C (As you can see in the answers). And there's a paradox in gsoap files, because there's an autogenerated header file being used in a C source, `wsseapi.c` which uses C++ features. If I could solve this problem, then I think compiling and linking wsseapi.c as well could fix the problem (As someone in the comments mentioned, the missing function is actually defined in the C source file.)

However, I am giving up in this whole solution, because I have found a simpler way to get data from my IP camera using `OpenCV` and `ffmpeg`. So I'm not gonna test anymore.

Thank you all for helping.

Comment: It seems like it try to link again C-style function, but you compiled it as a C++ one. This error "undefined reference to `soap_wsa_sender_fault_subcode'" looks like a C function signature

Comment: Maybe! There are two files over there provided by gsoap, one of them is c and the other is cpp file for the same functionality, maybe there's some changes missing from the conversion to cpp.

Comment: What command line are you using to compile & link?

Comment: Bash! I'm compiling the code with qbuild, g++ and in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Are you sure `soap_wsa_sender_fault_subcode` is defined in the same file? In the current source at github it is defined in [wsapi.c](https://github.com/stoneyrh/gSOAP/blob/af73ab8e55c00b43556876de39bef5dd200d4ba9/gsoap/plugin/wsaapi.c#L1035) but not in [wsseapi.cpp](https://github.com/stoneyrh/gSOAP/blob/af73ab8e55c00b43556876de39bef5dd200d4ba9/gsoap/plugin/wsseapi.cpp).

Comment: You're right, the last function is defined in `wssapi.c`! It was my mistake. But when I include it there come up a lot of multiple definition errors.

Comment: Sorry, when I include it another problem arises! In the C source file, there's a header file included, which is a c++ header and uses std::vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I suspect is that you are trying to link some C code with C++. This can lead to linking errors caused by how names are mangled in C++ compared to C.

To resolve such issues you should wrap the functions that are compiled from a C source file in an `extern` scope:

```
extern "C" {
  int soap_wsa_sender_fault_subcode(struct soap *soap, const char *faultsubcode, const char *faultstring, const char *faultdetail);
}
```

This would prevent the enclosed functions to be mangled so that their reference in the object file can be correctly found and linked. You can find additional information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c).

Comment: Doing so around the whole cpp file will give me a lot of error like  `/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/istream.tcc:83:3: error: template with C linkage
   template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>`.  On the other hand, I don't want to change a library file! Any better way? The source file is named .cpp and there is another .c file with the same name there, but when I include it, in another header (generated with a script) there's vector library included and it gives me an unresolved include error.

Comment: You must not do it around the whole CPP file, you must do it around the forward declaration of the methods which come from the C environment. This is the correct solution, I never minded finding an hacky workaround since there is no need for one.

Comment: Well, the function that I miss is defined in cpp!

Comment: @Sheric you only need to `extern "C"` the function declaration ;; that then applies to the definition automatically

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurred because you tried to link C code with C++ code.

Let's say you have `wssapi.c` `wssapi.h` `main.cpp`. In your `main.cpp` do this

```
extern "C" {
    #include "wssapi.h"
}
```

Instead of only

```
#include "wssapi.h"
```